# Group by multple columns and return SUM of one column in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

- I have a csv file with many columns. For the example here, I used 6 columns in total:

[image]

- I am using Python3 and Pandas (I am not that familiar).
- My main target is to create a new csv file after baking the data in the current one (shown above). What I want to do in steps:

01) Aggregate the data: As a start, group the rows per ID and have:

1. the earliest **Start Date** for each **ID**
2. the latest **End Date** for each **ID**
3. the SUM of the value for each **ID**

02) Group the rows per ID and any Random columns I pick and have:

1. the earliest **Start Date** for each **ID**
2. the latest **End Date** for each **ID**
3. the SUM of the value for each **ID**
4. present the **Random1** and **Random2** values alongside the rest of the data (grouped)

Without grouping the data, I was able to get the earliest **Start Date**, the latest **End Date** and the SUM of the **Value**. The code is given below (for 1 ID):

```
#Get the first Start Date
minStartDate = df.loc[ df['ID'] == 56886, 'Start Date'].min()

#Get the last End Date
maxEndDate = df.loc[ df['ID'] == 56886, 'End Date'].max()

#Get the value sum
sumValue = df.loc[ df['ID'] == 56886, 'Value'].sum()
```

Then I grouped it by all the IDs:

```
for i in ID:
    #Get the first Start Date
    minStartDate = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'Start Date'].min()
    #Get the last End Date
    maxEndDate = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'End Date'].max()
    #Get the Value sum
    sumValue = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'Value'].sum()

print(maxEndDate)
```

and I got the correct values for the **maxEndDate**, **minStartDate**, **sumValue**, **ID** after printing. The issue is that it only showed values for one **ID** (the last one in the file):

In this case, that was the expected output (after ignoring the Random columns):

[image]

So, I have altered the script to:

```
minStartDate = {}
maxEndDate = {}
summyValue = {}
Key = {}
ID = df[' ID']

for i in ID:
    Key[i] = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'ID']
    #Get the first Start Date
    minStartDate[i] = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'Start Date'].min()
    #Get the last End Date
    maxEndDate[i] = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'End Date'].max()
    #Get the Value sum
    summyValue[i] = df.loc[ df['ID'] == i, 'Value'].sum()



print(summyValue,minStartDate,maxEndDate)
```

and in the terminal I am getting this:

[image]

Considering that the final expected output is:

[image]

how should I play around with the combination of the fields? In the for loop I am guessing I should include the **Random 1** and **Random 2** columns (key creation). Also, what is the best output from the for loop in order to export everything in a new CSV file?

Comment: why do you forget to add pandas tag.

Comment: It'd be much easier for someone to help and play with your data if you'd provide it in a format that's easily usable - not images...

Comment: @JonClements I think you beat me this time to post that comment.

Comment: No data (as text) =  no help from pandas community usually .

Comment: However, it looks like your starting point should be `df.groupby('ID').agg('Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum'})`... It's not really clear what you want to happen with the random columns...

Comment: So you want to fill Random1 and Random2 with value of  maximum repetition?

Comment: @JonClements I am getting an invalid syntax when I assign this rule to a variable.

Comment: yeah... I missed the opening `{` for the dict... but thanks for letting me know that :)

Comment: @Jon Clements I did not notice that! I hate when that happens. :P I have not edited your answer in case you were doing it at the same time. Many thanks. It seems to be working.

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer @ApoloRadomer. Next time dont forget to include pandas tag too

Comment: @Bharathshetty I will accept the answer. I just wanted to test the lambda version too in case it was not working. Unfortunately, I won't have time for this now. I forgot the Pandas tag. I did not notice that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill the random 1 and random2 with maximum repititon value then you can use agg with your own function i.e eg

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'r1': ['x','y','y','y','x','x','x'],
    'r2': ['t','I','t','t','c','c','c']
})

def max_rep(x):
    return x.value_counts().idxmax()

ndf = df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'r1': max_rep,'r2':max_rep})
```

or using lambda if you want that in one line

```
ndf = df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'r1': lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax(),'r2': lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()})
```

Output :

```
  id r1 r2
0   1  y  t
1   2  x  c
```

As Jon commented you can do all your steps in one line using agg i.e

```
df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg('Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', \
                 'Random 1':max_rep,'Random 2':max_rep})
```

In case you are looking to group along with random1 and random2 then you can use

```
df.groupby(['ID','Random 1','Random 2'],as_index=False).agg('Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum')
```